# Prove that for any prime $p,$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $1^n+2^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+\dots+n^1\equiv 2020\pmod{p}.$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Prove that for any prime $p,$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that
$1^n+2^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+\dots+n^1\equiv 2020\pmod{p}.$

Can I have hints for this problem? What I tried was finding $n$ for every prime, but I couldn't get any explicit formula.

Comment: Because site policy forbids answering questions from open contests, you should identify the contest, so that we can tell it has closed.

Comment: it USEMO 2019 P1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, I didn't make any stupid mistakes.

Let $$f(n)\equiv 1^n+2^{n-1}+3^{n-2}+\dots+n^1 \pmod{p}$$

Note that
$$f(n) \equiv (p+1)^n+(p+2)^{n-1}+(p+3)^{n-2}+\dots+(p+n)n^1 \pmod{p}
 $$
From where you can deduce that
$$f(n+p) \equiv 1^{n+p}+2^{n+p-1}+...+(p-1)^{n+2}+f(p) \pmod{p} \\
\equiv 1^{n+1}+2^{n}+...+(p-1)^{n-p+3}+f(p) \pmod{p}$$

Prove by induction on $k$ that
$$f(n+kp) \equiv 1^{n+p}+2^{n+p-1}+...+(p-1)^{n+2}+f(p) \pmod{p} \\
\equiv 1^{n+1}+1^{n+2}+...+1^{n+k}+2^{n}+2^{n+1}+...+2^{n+k-1}...+(p-1)^{n-p+3}+...+(p-1)^{n-p+k+2}+f(p) \pmod{p}$$

Next, note that for all $2 \leq k \leq p-1$ and all $n$ we have
$$k^m+k^{m+1}+...+k^{m+p-2}=(k-1)^{-1}k^m(1-k^{p-1})=0$$
since $k-1$ is invertible.

Moreover,
$$1^m+1^{m+1}+....+1^{m+p-2} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$$

Deduce from here that
$$f(n+(p-1)p) \equiv f(n)-1 \pmod{p}$$
for all $n$. The conclusion follows immediatelly.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence of hints, which mostly follows how I approached this problem based on wishful thinking that an olympiad problem has a nice solution, and also some backward deduction from the problem statement. You can reveal each part, though I encourage you to think about what the next part is first.

(Wishful thinking: $n$ is very likely to be a multiple of $p-1$, $p$, or $p+1$. This is a reasonable assumption, but not needed.)

Wishful thinking: 2020 is likely a red herring. It should work for all values $M$.

Wishful thinking: Knowing this suggests that we want to string multiple sequences together. To clarify what this means, we want $m$ consecutive sequences of $n$ terms to give us:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{mn} i^{mn+1-i} \equiv m \times (\sum_{i=1}^n i ^{n+1 - i }) \pmod{p} \quad \quad (1)$$

Obviously this is very unique, so what values of $n$ could work?

> Since the bases repeat every $p$ times (mod $p$), and the powers repeat every $p-1$ times (by FLT), so we have $ i ^ {j+ p(p-1) } \equiv (i+p(p-1)) ^ j \pmod{p}$, and thus $(1)$ holds. This suggests $n = k p(p-1)$.

> Wishful thinking: If for some $k$ we have $ \sum_{i=1}^n i ^{n+1 - i } = N \neq 0 \pmod{p}$, then we just need to solve $mN \equiv M \pmod{p}$, or that $m = MN^{-1}$.

> Let's investigate $k=1$.

> Show that $$ \sum_{i=1}^{p(p-1)} i ^{n+1 - i }  \equiv \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=0}^{p-2} i^j.$$

> This sum is much easier to deal with, e.g. using a geometric progression.

> As it turns out, the sum is $ \equiv -1 \neq 0$.

Hence we are done.